# How do i get total number of records for all days of a given month inside a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

How do i get total count of records in all days of a given month inside a for loop i.e.

Lets say in a month of 31 days, I would want my result to look like

> 2 0 0 5 0 4 0 0 0 1 3 0 8 0 76 0 7 6 0 0 4 0 0 0 7 0 0 55 0 0 7

This is what i have tried

```
for( $day = 1 ; $day <= $totaldays ; $day++ ) 
{
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT  count(*) FROM tablex WHERE DAY(date_c) = '$day'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);     
$values[$row[0]] = (int)$row[1];

echo $values[$row[0]]; 
}
```

What could be wrong with my SQL query?

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT  count(*) FROM tablex WHERE DAY(date_c) = '$day'") or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Since the result that i get is

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

The date format from my database is in timestamp i.e. **2017-07-02 00:00:28**

I have also tried to add **$dtb = date("Y-m-$days");** inside the for loop and added it to the SQL **..WHERE DAY(date_c) = '$dtb'")..** but still i get no values.

*Also what is the actual format for **DAY(date_c)** in the mysql query?*

Comment: why not use group by?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I want to use the result in a graph so i also need the zero(0) values where there is no count for that day

Comment: so? left join to a calendar table. I'm not a MySql guy so I can't give you the exact answer, but the logic is still the same - Create a calendar table, use it with a left join to your data table, and then you'll get 0 count for missing days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is expecting two columns in the result set.  Either do:

```
 $values[i] = (int)$row[0];
```

or return the day along with the value:

```
SELECT $day as dy, count(*) FROM tablex WHERE DAY(date_c) = '$day'
```

Answer (score 1):

at first, try to remove the `'` around $day. The request is trying to match DAY(date_c) = '1' instead DAY(date_c) = 1 when you use `'` around $day.

Your line should look like:
`$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT  count(*) FROM tablex WHERE DAY(date_c) = $day") or die(mysqli_error($link));`

In general, it is not the best Idea to fire SQL requests in a loop, that is slow and will be even slower when you need a wider range of data (like for a year) or will bring other Problems.
Depends on your table design, you could maybe do something like

```
SELECT DAY(date_c) AS day_num, count(*) AS day_record
FROM tablex 
GROUP BY DAY(date_c)
ORDER BY DAY(date_c)
```

Then you have all your results in one request. You need to iterate over the result and print it, which is a lot faster doing it in PHP than call 31 times the DB.

Comment: Looks interesting, let me give it a try

Comment: @gordon-linoff is also right, I didn't recognized the `$row[1]` error :). SQL results start counting at 0 as the most Arrays also do.

Comment: in your second solution since you discourage loop, where do you get the variable  *$day* in  *WHERE DAY(date_c) = $day*. ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You don't need the $day variable any more and also no loop. Try to send the SQL request in a tool like phpmyadmin or SQL workbench to see the results.

Comment: Its good but it skips zero values which are also part of the required results

Comment: You can do something like this: `$ar = array_fill(1, 31, 0);
$sql = [1 => 10, 5 => 30, 10 => 100];
print_r (array_replace($ar, $sql));`. No loops needed.